# Need assistance with SQL query to parse JSON data from BigQuery table

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, jsonparser

I am using BigQuery Sessions table to query product fields. But I am able to query only first row with hardcoded index value. Can someone please assist me with the SQL query to parse JSON?

Query:

```
select visitId, hits[OFFSET(0)].product[OFFSET(0)].productSKU, hits[OFFSET(0)].product[OFFSET(0)].v2ProductName 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`
LIMIT 5
```

[image]

Sample sessions table data:

```
[
  {
    "visitId": "1501583974",
    "hits": [
      {
        "product": [
          {
            "productSKU": "GGOEGESB015199",
            "v2ProductName": "Test 1"
          },
          {
            "productSKU": "GGOEGESB015200",
            "v2ProductName": "Test 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected outcome:
[image]

Comment: Could you rephrase your question to make it more understandable? Are you facing an issue while inserting your nested data into the BigQuery table? Or you want to know how to query it?

Comment: @KrishnuSengupta - I have updated the body. I just want to know how to query the JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the following query :

```
select visitId, n.productSKU, n.v2productName from (select visitId, m.product
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`, unnest(hits) as m
LIMIT 5), unnest (product) as n
```

In the inner query I am unnesting the array of structures ‘hits’ and in the outer query I am unnesting the inner array of structures ‘product’.

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @KrishanuSengupta. This is exactly what I was looking for. Also I found useful explanation on UNNEST. 
- To convert an ARRAY into a set of rows, also known as "flattening," use the UNNEST operator. UNNEST takes an ARRAY and returns a table with a single row for each element in the ARRAY.